# Python: How to generate two new columns in a pandas df, based on the order of the values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following table as input:

|  | x | y |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | -0.872803 | 137.097977 |
| 1 | -0.418766 | 821.549805 |
| 2 | -0.657833 | 712.427856 |
| 3 | -0.922091 | 126.871956 |
| 4 | -0.847130 | 217.126068 |
| 5 | 0.692070 | 2166.090820 |
| 6 | -0.858773 | 297.893188 |
| 7 | -0.466285 | 634.510315 |
| 8 | -0.774720 | 91.447876 |
| 9 | -0.111050 | 1200.390625 |
| 10 | 0.325138 | 1759.597900 |

And I need to generate something like this:

|  | x | y | pos_when_sorted_by_x | pos_when_sorted_by_y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | -0.872803 | 137.097977 | 9 | 8 |
| 1 | -0.418766 | 821.549805 | 3 | 3 |
| 2 | -0.657833 | 712.427856 | 5 | 4 |
| 3 | -0.922091 | 126.871956 | 10 | 9 |
| 4 | -0.847130 | 217.126068 | 7 | 7 |
| 5 | 0.692070 | 2166.090820 | 0 | 0 |
| 6 | -0.858773 | 297.893188 | 8 | 6 |
| 7 | -0.466285 | 634.510315 | 4 | 5 |
| 8 | -0.774720 | 91.447876 | 6 | 10 |
| 9 | -0.111050 | 1200.390625 | 2 | 2 |
| 10 | 0.325138 | 1759.597900 | 1 | 1 |

`pos_when_sorted_by_x` and `pos_when_sorted_by_y` are based on the location in the sorted dataframe by each of these columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following too:

```
dfs_x = df.sort_values(by='x', ascending=False)
dfs_y = df.sort_values(by='y', ascending=False)
df['pos_x'] = df.index.map(dfs_x.index.get_loc)
df['pos_y'] = df.index.map(dfs_y.index.get_loc)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `rank`:

```
df[['x_pos', 'y_pos']] = df.agg('rank', ascending=False).sub(1).astype(int)
print(df)

# Output:
           x            y  x_pos  y_pos
0  -0.872803   137.097977      9      8
1  -0.418766   821.549805      3      3
2  -0.657833   712.427856      5      4
3  -0.922091   126.871956     10      9
4  -0.847130   217.126068      7      7
5   0.692070  2166.090820      0      0
6  -0.858773   297.893188      8      6
7  -0.466285   634.510315      4      5
8  -0.774720    91.447876      6     10
9  -0.111050  1200.390625      2      2
10  0.325138  1759.597900      1      1
```

An alternative with numpy and `argsort`:

```
df[['x_pos', 'y_pos']] = np.argsort(np.argsort(-1*df, axis=0), axis=0)
print(df)

# Output:
           x            y  x_pos  y_pos
0  -0.872803   137.097977      9      8
1  -0.418766   821.549805      3      3
2  -0.657833   712.427856      5      4
3  -0.922091   126.871956     10      9
4  -0.847130   217.126068      7      7
5   0.692070  2166.090820      0      0
6  -0.858773   297.893188      8      6
7  -0.466285   634.510315      4      5
8  -0.774720    91.447876      6     10
9  -0.111050  1200.390625      2      2
10  0.325138  1759.597900      1      1
```

Note: `-1*` is because `argsort` have no option to descending order.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `pd.rank` with `ascending=False` and subtract 1 so the rank starts at zero.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [-0.872803,
  -0.418766,
  -0.657833,
  -0.922091,
  -0.84713,
  0.69207,
  -0.858773,
  -0.466285,
  -0.77472,
  -0.11105,
  0.325138],
 'y': [137.097977,
  821.549805,
  712.427856,
  126.871956,
  217.126068,
  2166.09082,
  297.893188,
  634.510315,
  91.447876,
  1200.390625,
  1759.5979]})

df['pos_x'] = (df.x.rank(ascending=False)-1).astype(int)
df['pos_y'] = (df.y.rank(ascending=False)-1).astype(int)
```

Output

```
           x            y  pos_x  pos_y
0  -0.872803   137.097977      9      8
1  -0.418766   821.549805      3      3
2  -0.657833   712.427856      5      4
3  -0.922091   126.871956     10      9
4  -0.847130   217.126068      7      7
5   0.692070  2166.090820      0      0
6  -0.858773   297.893188      8      6
7  -0.466285   634.510315      4      5
8  -0.774720    91.447876      6     10
9  -0.111050  1200.390625      2      2
10  0.325138  1759.597900      1      1
```